# Как создать поддомен в ipsmanager?

Tags: хостинг, dns, поддомены

Создал поддомен на ipsmanager, залил туда index файл. Потом зарегестрировал его в godaddy, но почему то при переходи на него отображается ошибка. Может я что-то не так сделал?
[image: godaddy]

[image: поддомен в ipsmanager]

Comment: А какая связь между ipsmanager и goddady ? что вы зарегестрировали на goddady? что за ошибка?

Comment: Можно увидеть ошибку?

Comment: И ещё: godaddy - это хостинг, на котором у вас расположен ispmanager?

Comment: ipsmanager - это хостинг на котором расположены файлы для основного сайта и для лендинга, сайт расположен на на адресе www.yepworld.org, а лендинг на поддомене forum.yepworld.org. Godaddy - это регистратор доменных имен, где мы зарегестрировали yepworld.org. И когда основной сайт не отображался на godaddy нужно было прописать хост. Я думал для поддомена так же нужно сделать, но почему то не работает.

Comment: [Это сама ошибка](http://forum.yepworld.org)